# In Angular 8 Router parent route remains the same when navigating to the route with other parent

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular-router, nested-routes

I'm working on a project written on Angular (v8.2.8) and use router with the same version. The architecture of the routing is the following:

I have app-routing.module.ts where I have 3 entries for `routes` array:
`Shell.childRoutes([...array of routes]),
Case.childRoutes([...array of routes]),
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' }`

Shell - that is parent component for app internal pages.
Case - that is parent component for app public pages.

Method child routes do almost the same for both components:

```
export class Shell {
  static childRoutes(routes: Routes): Route {
    return {
      path: 'app',
      component: ShellComponent,
      children: routes,
      canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
      data: { reuse: true }
    };
  }
}
```

and

```
export class Case {
  static childRoutes(routes: Routes): Route {
    return {
      path: '',
      component: CaseComponent,
      children: routes,
      data: { reuse: true }
    };
  }
}
```

App have `dashboard` component for `Shell` parent and `home` component for `Case` parent. 
User loads the page at `home` route and markup is the following:

```
<app-root>
  <app-case> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-home></app-home>
  </app-case>
</app-root>
```

And after redirect to the `dashboard` route I expect to have the following markup:

```
<app-root>
  <app-shell> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
  </app-shell>
</app-root>
```

But I receive

```
<app-root>
  <app-case> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
  </app-case>
</app-root>
```

So the exact issue is in test case:
User is on a route which exist in `Shell` parent.
Then if user will be redirected to any route in `Case` parent - the parent will stays the Shell. And the same situation works in other direction. If `Case` route was load first, after redirect to `Shell` route parent will stay the case.

I tried to edit different parameters in the `childRoutes` method, but no success, I just don't understand is it the issue in the engine, or I just need to specify some additional parameters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically I resolved this issue. For those who had the same issue - for me issue was in custom route reusable strategy which was implemented. When I was switching from `Case` to `Shell` route-reusable-strategy function `shouldReuseRoute` returned true, so route was reused.